# SSH from inside a docker container

Tags: java, docker, ssh, sftp

So, I haven't worked with docker for very long. But this is the first time where I've had a requirement to ssh OUT of a docker container. It should be straight forward because I know I can connect to databases pull files from repositories. But  for some reason I cannot seem to connect to a remote sftp server. Interestingly on my local it runs fine (no docker), but when building on Jenkins the tests cannot connect. Even to a MOCK server that I set up and put a test file on before the tests run. Running on Jenkins also makes it difficult to debug what the issue is.

Im using Jcraft to get the connection below:

```
public static Session getSession (String host, String user) throws JSchException{
        JSch jsch = null;
        int port = 22;
        if (JunitHelperContext.getInstance.isJunit()){
            port = JunitHelperContext.getInstance.getSftpPort();
        Session session = jsch.getSession(user,host,port);
        java.util.Properties config  = new  java.util.Properties();
        config.put(“StrictHostKeyChecking”, “no”);
        if (!JunitHelperContext.getInstance.isJunit()){
            config.put(“PreferredAuthentications”, “publickey”);
            jsch.setKnownHosts(”~/.ssh/known_hosts”);
            jsch.addIdentity(“~/.ssh/id_rsa”);
        }
        session.setConfig(config);
        session.connect();

        return session;
    }
}
```

My requirement is to go out and read a file and process it. I can build the kit fine using a non-docker template. The file is found and processed. Running it inside a docker container though, I get this error when I try to connect:

```
Invalid Key Exception: the security strength of SHA-1 digest algorithm is not sufficient for this key size. 
com.jcraft.jsch.JSchException:  Session.connect: java.io.IOException:   End of IO Stream Read
```

So this seems like a security issue. In production, the certificates are on the server and they can be read in that /.ssh directory. But this is a mock Jcraft server, and I shouldnt need to authenticate.

Is there a piece I am missing here? Configuration in the docker file ?Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to enable Java's JCE unlimited strength stuff in the docker container:

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html

There are export restrictions on this cryptography stuff and I'll bet your docker container has the weak strength exportable jars.

Copy local_policy.jar and US_export_policy.jar into the docker container with the Dockerfile and overwrite what's there.

Follow the instructions at that link.